# how to generate pdf of dynamically change datgrid table of jquery

Tags: php, jquery

My problem is that i use Data Grid table for showing fetching data from database.i used Jquery Data Grid table which perform Columb wise sorting,pagination,columb hiding according to what user want to view.but i want to generate pdf with proper header in every page with a4 size printable according to that table in jquery.

Comment: you could use the [HTML Table Export plugin](http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php)

Comment: hi carlodurso thanks a lot for your answer but i faced one problem that is this code given by (HTML Table Export plugin) generated only four columb but i need to generate more than four columb .i tried a lot to solve this problem but i can't find solution.plz help me...